# Синтаксис обращения к элементам XML через SimpleXML (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, prestashop

В коде интернет-магазина есть фрагмент:

```
if (!file_exists($xml_file) || !$xml = @simplexml_load_file($xml_file)) {
        $this->errors[] = "cannot load";
        return false;
}
if (!$xml['version'] || !$xml['name']) {
    $this->errors[] = "version and name required";
    return false;
}
```

Пример обрабатываемого XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<theme>
 <version value="1.4">
  <ccc available="true" />
  <guest_checkout available="true" />
  <one_page_checkout available="true" />
  <store_locator available="true" />
 </version>
 
 <name value="Sound Theme" />
</theme>
```

Проблема в том, что условие `(!$xml['version'] || !$xml['name'])` возвращает false, несмотря на то, что элементы **version** и **name** в xml есть. Пробовал обращаться к ним в стиле `$xml->{'version'}` - все работает.
Не может быть, что в таком крупном продукте неправильно написали код работы с XML. Может быть, доступ к элементам через синтаксис [] работает с определенной версии PHP? У меня версия 5.3.13.
Прошу подсказать, в чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить, не меняя исходный код интернет-магазина.

Comment: `$xml['version']` это работа с массивом, а у вас `$xml` - __объект__. Понимаете разницу между ними?

Comment: Это код из крупного проекта (https://github.com/PrestaShop/themeinstallator/blob/master/themeinstallator.php строка 386). Я думаю авторы проекта знают разницу между массивом и объектом, к тому же у других людей работает все, иначе код был бы исправлен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того что синтаксис `$xml['version']` говорит о том, что у объекта `$xml` берется значение атрибута.

В вашем же `$xml`

```
<theme>
    <version value="1.4">
        <ccc available="true" />
        <guest_checkout available="true" />
        <one_page_checkout available="true" />
        <store_locator available="true" />
    </version>
    
    <name value="Sound Theme" />
</theme>
```

у корневого элемента `theme` этих атрибутов нет.

Потому-то и не проходит проверка

```
!$xml['version'] || !$xml['name']
```

Для того чтобы разобраться, я скачал бесплатный шаблон для prestashop (вообще не знаю зачем). И в нем я увидел приблизительно следующее:

```
<theme version="1.0" name="dixio" directory="dixio">
    <author name="Presta Theme Maker" email="presta.theme.maker@gmail.com" url="http://presta-theme-maker.com/"/>
```

Видите? Здесь у тега `theme` есть оба проверяемых атрибута.

Таким образом, вывод - предоставленный вами xml-файл имеет неподдерживаемый скриптом импорта/экспорта формат.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Видимо мне попались кривые шаблоны, которые сбили меня с толку.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так. Надеюсь что помог

```
$xml->version[0]['value'];
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне не нужно править код проекта. Мне нужно понять, почему он у меня не работает.